# Unable to create new team project in TFS2010

Tags: team-project

I am using TFS2010 and have added 3 projects in default collection.
But now I want to add one more project.
So, When I create new project , I am getting error as below :

> TF30170: The plugin Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.WorkItemTracking
>   failed during task WITs from group WorkItemTracking.
>
> Explanation  Plugin error text: “TF237162: There is insufficient
>   system memory on the Team Foundation Server SQL Server to run this
>   query.”
>
> User Action  Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

I am admin user of machine.

I have also new collection and tried to create new team project , I am getting same error.

Can anyone help ??

Comment: Please provide more information. Server specs for the TFS DB server would be helpful but the error is fairly self explanatory unless you have more extenuating circumstances.

Comment: TFS2010 is installed on Windows server 2008 R2  and system's c drive has 200GB left.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue is in the database of the TFS, it seems that the disk space of the server hosting the database is too low or empty.

If you are the administrator of the server, try to free the disk space, you can also shrink the logs to increase the available space.

Also the issue may be related to the reporting services, open the TFS admin console, disable the reporting services then create your team project again then enable it at the end.
Hope this helps